# Importing a function from a module that has a import on the module

Tags: python, import, importerror

May I have no searched thoroughly enough, please link me to it.

I am trying to import a function from another module. That modules also import some functions that the module.

Here's the folder system:

```
/foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

`foo.py`

```
from .bar import _function
```

`bar.py`

```
from .foo import some_other_function
```

which results in

```
ImportError : cannot import name 'some_other_function'
```

when a script in `foo.py` is ran.

Extra info :

`__init__.py`

```
from foo import w_function, y_function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to Cyclic imports.
You can do -

from bar import *

and

from foo import *

Not sure whether this is advisable or not.

Also, in your case you can put your import statements inside the functions where the imports are actually required.

Your problem has a discussion and solutions here - [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)